# ssh public key fingerprint does not match. Man-in-the-middle attack?

Tags: ssh, public-key-encryption, fingerprint, public-key, man-in-the-middle

I have a cloud server of IP address `39.106.xx.xxx` hosted on Aliyun. I generated a RSA 2048 ssh keypair (`~/.ssh/rsa_bj.pub` and `~/.ssh/rsa_bj`) on my local laptop using `ssh-keygen`, and imported the public key file to the server through console webpage of Aliyun.

When I `ssh` connect to the server, it shows the fingerprint of my public key, beginning with `Meg4xe`. But this fingerprint does not match my local fingerprint, which I got by `ssh-keygen -l -f ~/.ssh/rsa_bj.pub`, beginning with `qEqyMv`.

Does this mean that I ran into a man-in-the-middle attack? Or does it mean that the two fingerprints were calculated using different rehash algorithms on the same public key?

[my ssh config file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ffy45.png)
[my commands](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OoCZv.png)

Comment: Although the fingerprints do not match, I can login to the server using the keypair specified in the `config` file.

Comment: The fingerprint shown to you by `ssh` was the fingerprint of the host key, not the fingerprint of your user key. This host key is then saved in your `.ssh/known_hosts`.

Comment: Thank you, @alvits . Now I know the difference between host keys and user keys. But I still do not know how to verify that I'm not in a MITM attack, since the only thing I ensure is the public user key. I cannot plug in a monitor to that server to check the fingerprint because it's a clout server.